# How to uninstall git installed from git-scm.com (macOS)?

Tags: git, macos

I recently installed git directly from `git-scm.com` on my Mac (running version 2.19.0), but I am interested in installing the homebrew version.

How should I go about executing `sudo rm -rf` without accidentally deleting Apple's git version? Or, maybe I can manually delete the required directories?

Doing `which git`, I am met with `/usr/local/bin/git`.

Comment: What is the output of `git --version`? The Apple version is in `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: I am running 2.19.0

Comment: Specifically what does it output?

Comment: "git version 2.19.0"

Comment: Then I'd say you could probably `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/git`, although it might've set symlinks perhaps or added an alias to your `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: It's just a `.dmg`, right? Can't you just drag it to the trash like any other application?

Comment: @Chris, No, `/usr/local/bin` is a directory on the system.

Comment: I know what `/usr/local/bin` is, but OP said they installed from git-scm.com. As far as I can tell the Git povided for macOS on git-scm.com is a `.dmg`. OP, how, _exactly_, did you install Git?

Comment: I think `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/git `did it. Doing `which git`, I get `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: @Chris I'm pretty sure I did `git clone https://github.com/git/git`, which was on their site.

Comment: @l'L'l What about the remnants of usr/local/bin - can those be deleted?

Comment: @Art: Yes, I'd say so; I'm not sure what you're seeing, although none of Apple's `git` is stored in there. Just don't get rid of `bin`, `lib`, `include`, `share` if you have other things installed.